# Invariant distribution of a Markov chain - joint probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains, invariance, transition-matrix

I have found the following invariant distribution $\pi$, invariant w.r.t. my transition probability matrix: $$P = \begin{bmatrix}
0.8 & 0.2 \\ 0.5 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix}$$

$\pi = [0.7142857, 0.2857143]$

I now want to know - given that the initial state is drawn at random from $\pi$ - what is the joint probability that $X_{t} = 1$ and $X_{t+1} = 1$. Is it right to say that it is 0.7142857? Or am I not understanding what the meaning of invariant distribution is?

I also read that the joint ($X_t, X_{t+1}$) has to do with $X_{t}$ ~ $\pi$  and $X_{t+1}$|$X_{t}$ ~ $P$, but not sure of how to use this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(X_t=1,X_{t+1}=1)=P(X_{t+1}=1|X_t=1)P(X_t=1)=(0.8)(0.7142857)$ (assuming that your states are named $1$ and $2$). The distribution of $X_t$ is $\pi$ for all $t$ but $P(X_{t+1}=1|X_t=1)$ is given by the transition matrix.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! It's much clearer now

Comment: Is there any specific book / online resource you could suggest me on topics like this one (exchangeability, Markov Chains, MCMC)?

Comment: K B Atherya is an authority on Markov chains, MCMC etc. He has a book on measure and probability which contains these things.  @yoyo_24

Comment: There are several modern textbooks devoted to Markov chains:  [1] Brémaud, Pierre. Markov chains: Gibbs fields, Monte Carlo simulation, and queues. Vol. 31. Springer Science & Business Media, 2013.   [2]  Norris, James R., and James Robert Norris. Markov chains. No. 2. Cambridge university press, 1998. [3]  Levin, David A., and Yuval Peres. Markov chains and mixing times. Vol. 107. American Mathematical Soc., 2017.   (PDF available at https://yuvalperes.com/markov-chains-and-mixing-times-2/)